# Tweak or customize cost around people on the costmap

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-hydro, costmap, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to tweak or customize the costmap my turtlebot generates such that it assigns higher costs to the cells ahead of a moving person, based on his direction of motion. That is, I want it to predict where the person will be in the next few seconds in order to more intelligently perform its path-planning.

I will be using the [PCL People Detection Code](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pcl/html/people_2apps_2main__ground__based__people__detection_8cpp_source.html) to first of all detect and recognize that an 'object' is a person. I will be using the [costmap_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) and [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) packages for the costmap generation. So once I combine these two, I assume it's just a matter of detecting the direction of motion and then knowing which cells' costs to elevate.

Any thoughts on how to do this? How do I detect direction of motion? How do I track motion of ONLY 'people objects'? How do I customize and choose which cells to elevate costs?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141341/tweak-or-customize-cost-around-people-on-the-costmap/) by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To ellaborate on what Austin said, I worked on precisely this problem.

In the people stack that Austin referenced, there is a laser-based people tracker. Their direction is based on tracking their motion from frame to frame.

Be sure to check out Layered Costmaps in the Hydro navigation package (http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d). There's a groovy fork in my repo available as well. https://github.com/DLu/navigation/tree/groovy_dev My implementation uses a Proxemics-based layer, the code for which can be found in the social_navigation_layers package in the people stack. https://github.com/DLu/people

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-03-19**:
Thank you; I'll check those resources out and let you & Austin know whether I still have any questions or not :)

**Comment by [mateus03](https://answers.ros.org/users/18781/mateus03/) on 2014-06-04**:
Thank you! Those resources were just what I needed to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@david-lu did some great research about this very subject during his time at Willow Garage.

He made a great [poster](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Edvl1/publications/TuningCostmapsPoster.pdf), and I think his code is available in his fork of the [people stack](https://github.com/DLu/people).

There was also a blog post on the Willow Garage website, but it appears to be down at the moment. there's a mediocre copy in the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:za2T9BmQ4_YJ:www.willowgarage.com/blog/2013/05/03/improving-navigation-interactions+&cd=11&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&lr=lang_en%7Clang_de)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-03-19**:
Thank you; I'll check those resources out and let you & David know whether I still have any questions or not :)